# Crystal report COM exception error

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my crystal report, I'm using a `UFL` function `ExDllclsExDllConvertLocal`. This function is working fine in any formula field. But whenever I try to insert that formula field to a text object, my project is showing following error. (sorry for my bad English)

Custom tool error:

> "Code generator 'ReportCodeGenerator' failed.  Exception stack =
>   CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.
>   ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The ) is missing. Details: errorKind Error in File crptMoneyReceipt
>   12048_21920_{DA2FED10-3D68-4E52-93B6-717B7B875D8D}.rpt: Error in
>   formula  test:  'ToText(mid(ExDllclsExDllConvertLocal
>   ({sp_GetMoneyReciept.TransactionAmount}),1,instr(ExDllclsExDllConvertLocal ({sp_GetMoneyReciept.TransactionAmount}),".")-1))' The ) is missing.
>   Details: errorKind    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportClassWriter..ctor(String
>   filePath)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportClassWriter..ctor(String
>   filePath, String resourceNamespace)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator.GenerateCode(String
>   inputFileName, String inputFileContent)"

Comment: have you tried looking for the missing ")" that is mentioned in stack trace at line 3?

Comment: is this a dll? "ExDllclsExDllConvertLocal"

Comment: @besem I've been using this function for last 8/10 years and in different crystal report versions. It was always working fine. It is still working fine when I'm using it to convert any number to comma separated format. But this error shows up when I try to insert this formula field into a text object. Recently I updated the runtime to CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_19.

Comment: @read yes, this is a dll.